# Input Value - undefined or not showing up

Tags: javascript, input, push, default-value

i am coding To do list app, but javascript code has some errors. so the problem is that when Li shows up it is "undefined" or sometimes even blank space
**HTML**

```
    <section>
    <div class="list-app">
        <ul id="list">
            <li>Hell</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="bottom">
            <input type="text" name="game"  placeholder="Type Your List">
            <img src="add.png" id="add">
            <img src="trash.jpg" id="remove">

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

and **javascript**

```
var remove = document.querySelector('#remove');
var add = document.getElementById('add');
var textPlace = document.querySelector('input');
var listSingle = document.querySelector('LI');
var input = document.getElementsByName('game');
var items = [''];

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  items.push = [input.value];

document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<li>' + items + '</li>';


})
```

dont mind other code it's just copped version for add button

Comment: `var items = [];` instead. Then `items.push = [input.value];` should be `items.push(input.value);`.

Comment: It would be nice if you included the error that is being printed by the browser's console of if you uploaded your code to a platform like jsfiddle. That way it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the following code. This returns a collection of `NodeList` ([MDN Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName))
    document.getElementsByName('game')

that being said, if you need to get value of input, you have to use the following code

```
items.push(input[0].value);
```

However, I think this is not a good practice to use `getElementsByName`, I would prefer to use `getElementById` and add `id` attribute to `input` element.

also, if you want to list input value as an individual list item, use the following code.

```
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = items.map(item => '<li>' + item + '</li>');
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks it helped

Comment: glad to hear that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The items variable is an array, which you are initially adding the an empty string as the first item in that array.

In your onclick function, you then reference that array.   The reference is to the array object itself (rather than the items in the array, or a string of all the array items).

What I think you are aiming for here is to loop through each item in the array and create the li element for each array item, i.e. something along the lines of:

```
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = “”; // reset list
Items.forEach(function(item){
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML += '<li>' + item + '</li>';
})
```

On my phone atm, but will type a proper snippet when I’m back at my desk.

**Edit** 
Added a snippet showing this working. This corrects a couple of typos in the question.

```js
var remove = document.querySelector('#remove');
var add = document.getElementById('add');
var textPlace = document.querySelector('input');
var listSingle = document.querySelector('li');
var input = document.getElementsByName('game');
var items = []; // this contained "". This made first item an empty string.

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log("Clicked");
  items.push(textPlace.value);
  // .push is a method: use (param) rather than = [param]
  // getElementsByName gets an array of elements. Can't get .value of multiple elements this way. QuerySelector gets single element, so input has been replaced with textPlace.

  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = ""; // reset list
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML += '<li>' + item + '</li>';
  });
});
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="list-app">
    <ul id="list">
      <li>Hell</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="bottom">
      <input type="text" name="game" placeholder="Type Your List">
      <img src="add.png" id="add">
      <img src="trash.jpg" id="remove">

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, the result is that the list gives me blank space insted of 'undifined'

Comment: There were a couple of typos in the original JS that prevented this from working.  The post by StackSlave is a more complete solution, but thought it would be useful to add a snippet anyway showing your post working with some minor tweaks - hopefully that will be helpful in understanding why your original code didn't work .

Answer (score 0):

Read my comment. Here's what I'm guessing you really want to do:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let get, post, doc, html, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, aC, rC, tC; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
get = (url, success, context)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('GET', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  x.send();
}
post = function(url, send, success, context){
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('POST', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      x.send(send);
    }
    else{
      const fd = new FormData;
      for(let k in send){
        fd.append(k, JSON.stringify(send[k]));
      }
      x.send(fd);
    }
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
doc = document; html = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
aC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.add(...a);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.remove(...a);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.toggle(...a);
  return tC;
}
// you can put all the below on a separate page in a load Event - besides the end load
const text_in = I('text_in'), list_add = I('list_add'), list = I('list');
function addText(){
  let v = text_in.value.trim();
  if(v !== ''){
    const li = M('li'), div = M('div'), remove = M('input');
    div.textContent = v; remove.type = 'button'; remove.value = 'remove'; aC(remove, 'remove');
    remove.onclick = ()=>{
      list.removeChild(li); text_in.focus();
    }
    li.appendChild(div); li.appendChild(remove); list.appendChild(li);
  }
  text_in.value = ''; text_in.focus();
}
list_add.onclick = addText;
text_in.onkeyup = e=>{
  if(e.key === 'Enter')addText();
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  padding:0; margin:0; font-size:0; border:0; box-sizing:border-box; outline:none; overflow:hidden; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%; background:#ccc;
}
.main{
  padding:10px;
}
input,#list_adder>ul>li{
  font:bold 22px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;  
}
input[type=text]{
  width:calc(100% - 75px); padding:3px 5px; border-radius:3px; 
}
input[type=button]{
  cursor:pointer; width:75px; background:linear-gradient(#1b7bbb,#147); color:#fff; padding:3px 0; border-radius:5px;
}
input[type=button].remove{
  position:absolute; right:5px; top:5px; background:linear-gradient(#b75757,#502323); font-size:14px;
}
#list_adder>ul{
  list-style:none;
}
#list_adder>ul>li{
  position:relative; background:#eee; padding:3px 5px; border:1px solid #000; margin-top:7px; border-radius:2px;
}
#list_adder>ul>li>div{
  display:inline-block; font-size:14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <section id='list_adder'>
      <input id='text_in' type='text' placeholder='Add Something Here' /><input id='list_add' type='button' value='ADD' />
      <ul id='list'></ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```